# The text goes over the image and not under it

Tags: html, css

The problem is that when I added an image to my html page,and I tried to write something to continue my working,the text was going over the image.I want the text to be going under the image.I don't want to use 50 "br" tags so that I can write under it.Do you know what's the problem guys ?

```
.poze {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.199219) 0px 0px 20px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    padding: 8px;
    "

}
.cerculet {
    display: block;
}
.cerculet:after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content:' ';
}
.cerculet p {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.cerculet h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
    height: 145%;
    width: 1.6em;
    height: 1.6em;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

That was the CSS.Now I'll post  the html code:

```
<h2>
    <div class="cerculet">
        <h2>2 </h2>
        <p>
            <font size="5" face="Cambria">
                Gripa Spaniola (1918 - 1919):<br>
                A ucis intre 50 si 100 de milioane de oameni din intreaga<br>
                lume in mai putin de 2 ani
            </font>
        </p>
    </div>
</h2>
<br>
<img src="http://s6.postimg.org/6oyuxe1e9/Spanish_Flu.jpg" class="poze" style="position:absolute; left:150px;">
<div>
    <h1>
        As you can see,the text doesn't go under my image.How to fix this problem guys?
    </h1>
</div>
```

I hope you'll understand the code.I mean,I used that "4 spaces indent" or whatever and I don't know if that's the right way to post the code.If I copy/paste all,it won't show it right..
https://jsfiddle.net/9hw89uog/

Comment: First of all, you've got an quote in your css (`.poze`). Second, I'm not sure if your allowed to have an `h2` tag inside an another `h2` tag...

Could you make an working example at [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)? Than people could easily test some things and help you out...

Comment: I never heard of jsfiddle...I posted my codes there but I don't know what to do with the result then..Another thing:there's no quote in `.poze` actually.I thought that " should be there after the CSS is written.I thought it works like a </tag>

Comment: If your code will run like it does on your project, save it an post the link in your question. Than people can go to the code, run it, test something and save an edited version. Than people can link to the edited version, and post the edits here.

Comment: I guess this is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/9hw89uog/

Comment: Indeed. If you could put that inside the question, you're helping yourself and others ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position:absolute` from your image styles, it is an inline style in your case

Comment: Ok,that worked but now there's another problem.I want the picture a bit centered(compared to the upper text).Not centered in the middle of the page.As you saw,I'm doing all the writing on half the page not on full page(continous writing).When I was using `position:absolute`,I could've centered a bit.

Comment: You can use `margin-left` on the picture

Comment: Thanks.But I don't know where to put `margin-left`.Is that a css or html ?

Comment: <img src="##" class="poze" style=" margin-left:120px;"> simple

Comment: You can use inline css like you have been `src="http://s6.postimg.org/6oyuxe1e9/Spanish_Flu.jpg" class="poze" style="margin-left:150px; left:150px;">`.  but i'd recommend external stylesheets and trageting the image there

Comment: you can also use any number you want at place of 120px.

Comment: @ Antonio, if you are using position then use left or else simply margin-left is enough.. :)

Comment: Got it guys.Thanks a lot.But I have one more question.Is there a way so that I can literally move all the CSS(<style>.......</style>) away from my html code and put it in another folder/file or something so that the html to be more nice looking ?

Comment: sure put this in the head `<link rel="stylesheet" href="" />` the href is file ex. `style.css`

Comment: Nope.Not working.I added `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` to the head of the page(after removing the css code and moved it in a notepad named "style.css") and it isn't applying the css.

Comment: the `style.css` needs to be in the same folder as the index file

Comment: It is!I made a folder HTML then in that folder I made another folder named HTML then in that folder there's "Proba temporala.html" and "style.css".And is not working.I wonder if there's a problem with the way I wrote the CSS code.I tried both  <style>...</style> and {...} (without involving the <style> tag) and in the both ways,is not working.

Comment: The style tags are not needed inside .css files i suggest looking over [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) for more infromation

Comment: Is still not working !! I removed all the style tags and read that and it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution: https://jsfiddle.net/73s1c4h1/2/

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <img src="https://images.nga.gov/images/bindo.jpg" class="poze"style="margin-left:150px;">
    <div>
        <h1 >
            Now the text should be clear of the image and positioned below it. 
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

This involves using the all famous "clearfix" CSS solution. You will need to wrap the image and text in a div, then place class="clearfix" in that div. The clearfix CSS is here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/
It will force the div element to clear the children elements.

Clearfix CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content:" ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

The second solution is a bit simpler; just set **position: relative;** rather than absolute. https://jsfiddle.net/73s1c4h1/1/

You may also need to change **left: 150px** to **margin-left: 150px**